# Can I do a default error treatment to all ajax?

Tags: jquery, ajax

It is possible to add a default error treatment to all ajax in my web site?

I want to do something like that:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: '<?= isset($insumo) ? $this->url( 'insumo', [ 'action' => 'editar' ] ) : $this->url( 'insumo', [ 'action' => 'criar' ] ) ?>',
    data: dados,
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function( r ) {
        [Code here]
    }, error: function( r ) {
          if( r.status == 302 ) {
                // Redirect to login
          }
    });
```

But I don't want to do that in all of my ajax function (There's a lot of they in the system).

There's a way to add that default action with something like javascript prototype or should I just create a function and call it in every ajax?

Comment: yes - https://api.jquery.com/ajaxError/

Comment: If you are looking for `interceptors` use `ajaxComplete` this will handle entire ajax call in your application.

Comment: Thank you so much for answer, I'll use both to simplify my code xD

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Register global ajax error handler for jQuery.

```
$.ajaxError(function() {
  console.log("ajax error");
});


$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: '<?= isset($insumo) ? $this->url( 'insumo', [ 'action' => 'editar' ] ) : $this->url( 'insumo', [ 'action' => 'criar' ] ) ?>',
    data: dados,
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function( r ) {
        [Code here]
    });
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer with example, It'll surely help me to simplify my code xD